# What are the replacements for the methods getPathParameters and getQueryParameters in resteasy?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I would like to replace the deprecated type ClientRequest by javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation etc.
However, the methods getPathParameters and getQueryParameters are missing.
Are there any replacements or do I have to write them myself?

Comment: Please show some code. There's not enough context to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple path and query parameters one has to call `resolveTemplate` and `queryParam` multiple times.

Other than that there seems to be:

```
ResteasyUriInfo resteasyUriInfo = new ResteasyUriInfo(webTarget.getUri());
resteasyUriInfo.getPathParameters();
resteasyUriInfo.getQueryParameters();
```